# Next.js: logout handler removes token from localhost but not when testing it on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Working on localhost:3000
[image]

Here is the problem
[image]

Here it is the code root of the page (sitename/api/logout):

```
var cookie = require("cookie");
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("token", "", {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
      sameSite: "strict",
      path: "/",
    })
  );
  res.status(200).json({ sonuc: "exit success" });
}
```

the code work for localhost correctly, but when I deploy the project on vercel this is not working I mean the 'token' cookie is not manipulate so it still has jwt code of block how can I deal with this issue

Comment: what do you mean by "the 'token' cookie is not manipulate so it still has jwt code of block"

Comment: when you say "the code works for localhost", what do you mean, what is the result you get on localhost and how does it differ with the other one? Can you share the expected result please

Comment: I want to change called 'token', so when i log in with auth system there will be a token in the cookies from browser but then when I want to log out I cant change to null the cookie of 'token'

Comment: when you say "the code works for localhost", I mean that when the project run the in my own pc so localhost:3000 'npm run dev' is correctly I can set the token with null or empty string but on the vercel.com this is not working so I cant change,

Comment: Thank you for sharing the gifs. They make the issue much clearer.

Comment: What are the browsers you are testing this in? Are they the same for both localhost and prod server?

Comment: yes I use the same browser Brave, then i try on windows 10 Edge then the result the same